# update image in database gives empty row

Tags: php, file, upload

I'm trying to update images in my database. Of course, I allow 1 image/input to update the right one, but somehow it doesn't get my '$file' variable. When I submit it, it says 'undefinied index: file' but I don't get why. Here's my update code:

```
    if (!empty($_POST['file'])) {
      $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE cardimages SET image = ? WHERE id = ?");
      $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
      if (is_uploaded_file($file)) {
        $imgData = file_get_contents($file);
        $stmt->bind_param('si', $imgData, $_POST['id']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
      }
    }
```

and my input:

```
<input id="file-upload" type="file" name="file" id="file" style="display: none;" />
```

'display: none' is because I use a label to make the button look better.

Comment: Can you share the method that is triggered when the form is submitted? Did you echo what is found inside $file variable.

Comment: Are you really storing binary image data in the database?

Comment: I don't use form here, because my php is in the same page as the html. @MarkusZeller why, what's the problem with it?

Comment: It is more common to store them in files and store a link to the image in databases to keep database as small and as performant as possible. It is also faster for the webserver serving files than database requests. Only you can store binary data it does not mean you should.

Comment: Well, good to know that. I think I should start it again then.

Comment: Does the form have `enctype='multipart/form-data'`?